# Using an en dash to separate a page and line range

Tags: american-english, dashes, range-inclusion

When writing a range of pages and line numbers, would I use an en dash to separate the range, or is it more appropriate to use "through" in this situation?

Refer to page 12, line 3–page 13, line 15.

Refer to page 12, line 3, through page 13, line 15.

Comment: That little hyphen isn't going to serve much of a purpose. Something has to hold numbers 12 and 3 together, then 13 and 15. I am thinking: *Refer to the range starting on page 12, line 3, and ending with page 13, line 15*.

Comment: Yes; unlike Word, ELU hasn'e a facility to stretch a hyphen to an en-dash where it might be appropriate. I usually cut-and-paste from a comment (temporary string of _c_'s if none as yet available). – – – – – from Yosef's.